# AbortController with fetch doesn't work in chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, fetch-api, abortcontroller

Here's the example by mdn: https://mdn.github.io/dom-examples/abort-api/

It works in firefox but not in chrome. I am on MacOs. Chrome version Version 116.0.5845.179 (Official Build) (arm64)

According to the matrix it should be working (for some time) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortSignal

I don't see anyone else complaining about this, am I the only one?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I had the Jam.dev plugin installed. Removing this fixed my issue: https://jam.dev